# Inlining manifest.js for webpack long-term caching with a deterministic [chunkhash]

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

See this thread for a discussion on effective long-term caching with webpack (particularly for vendor bundles):
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1315

I've successfully implemented a solution using this example (as mentioned in the above thread):
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/chunkhash

I am working on an isomorphic website. The server (which needs to require this file) is generated by webpack. I am able to get the solution to work by having the browser/client request `manifest.[chunkhash].js` from the server. However, I would like to inline the contents as to save an unnecessary http request.

In the example, it simply states:

`<!-- inlined minimized file "manifest.[chunkhash].js" -->`

How can I go about requiring a generated file, given that my server runs a generated file? It seems circular in logic.

To restate, my issue is with inlining the webpack-generated contents on a web request to a server that is running a webpack-generated file.

EDIT:

I was able to pull the contents and inline them on the server like so:

```
try {
    webpackAssetsFull = require('../../public/dist/webpack-assets.json');
    manifestFilename = _.last(webpackAssetsFull.assets.manifest.js.split('/'));
    manifestRaw = require('!!raw!uglify!../../public/dist/' + manifestFilename);
} catch (err) {
    console.warn('Waiting on webpack...');
}
```

And later when I render the html, I just throw the `manifestRaw` variable in between a script tag. This seems to work fine now.

I still have one issue. It appears that webpack is watching these generated files (which is pretty annoying for development). We run webpack with the watch feature in development. Whenever the `manifest.*.js` (or even the `webpack-assets.json`) file changes, the server (which requires these files) is recompiled. Does anyone know how to exclude those files from the watch system? I tried webpack externals but was not able to get it to work.